# Searchkick rails geospatial search not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, searchkick

I'm trying Searchkick on a small Rails app to perform geospatial searches, but I can't get it to work.

I have a Venue model:

```
class Venue < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
  searchkick locations: ["location"]

  def search_data
    attributes.merge location: [latitude, longitude]
    attributes.merge categories_title: categories.map(&:name)
  end
end
```

I have added data to my database, and I have run Venue.reindex too.

In my controller I'm trying to search by running:

```
  term = "london"
  res = Geocoder.search(term)
  @location = res.first.geometry['location'] # lat / lng
        @venues = Venue.search '*', where: {
    location: {
      near: [@location['lat'],@location['lng']],
      within: '2km'
    }
  }
```

Although I have valid data in my database, I always get an empty result. Looking at rails console, the query executed against elasticsearch is:

```
{  
   "query":{  
     "filtered":{  
      "query":{  
        "match_all":{  

        }
     },
     "filter":{  
        "and":[  
           {  
              "geo_distance":{  
                 "location":[  
                    -0.08077990000000002,
                    51.5037119
                 ],
                 "distance":"2km"
              }
           }
        ]
     }
  }
},
"size":1000,
"from":0,
"sort":{  
  "_geo_distance":{  
     "location":"51.5037119,-0.08077990000000002"
  }
 },
 "fields":[  
  ]
}
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm having the issue of no results when using a distance filter.

Comment: @Patelify not sure if you've tried what Caleuanhopkins mentioned. I ended up using a different gem that gives me lower level access to the query. My repo: https://github.com/pedropaf/elasticsearch-rails-geolocation/blob/master/app/controllers/venues_controller.rb

Comment: I did figure it out. Like most things in life, it was a user bug. I incorrectly typed the search_data method. I used 'latitude' instead of 'lat' and 'longitude' instead of 'lon' for the location attribute.

Answer (score 3):

Couple of things:

- Have you mapped `location` as a `geo_point`? If not, you can do:

  `searchkick merge_mappings: true, mappings: {venue: {properties: {locations: {type:"geo_point"}}}}, locations: ["location"]`
- `"distance":"2km"` - I've noticed elasticsearch is throwing errors with the unit of distance. Removing the `km` might help you. By default, ES uses km for distance so just throw in the distance number without the unit
- `match_all` - should work. I see your passing `*` which is good as ES sees this as a wildcard or a "search everything" command. if you're using the `match` query from searchkick, you may need to check if the "keyword" param is empty and if it is, pass `*` as leaving it empty won't work.

had your issue this morning and I was able to get results after making these changes

Answer (score 0):

We had this problem on one of our tables for a long time.  With a recent update of Searchkick we have solved it by using the method of always specifying a location with a hash, i.e. {lat: 37.12, lon: -121.12}, wherever possible.  The old method of using an array was prone to having mistakes in order in our code and in searchkick and using a hash ensures the correct value goes where it should go.  I started looking at the source code of searchkick and realized it would now take the hash everywhere so tried switching from the old documented method of array for location to hash, updating the model, then reindexing the table.